# Extracting formatted date after selecting date from datepicker using Python/Selenium

Tags: jquery, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

I'm currently working in Python 2.7.8 and the most current version of Selenium (2.45 I believe). I am going to use jQuery UI's datepicker example for my question. I have successfully verified that the current date is the date highlighted, then select a date that is 2 days out (or before if >= 26).

My question is how do you verify that the date displayed after picking the desired date using Python/Selenium? My code looks like:

```
def testStep4(self):
    # Verifying that the default date is today's date
    # Saves date element as integer
    dateelement1 = int(self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ui-datepicker-div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td.ui-datepicker-days-cell-over.ui-datepicker-today > a").text)

    # Saves today's date as integer
    dateelement2 = int(datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(),'%d'))

    # Validates that default date is today's date
    if dateelement1 == dateelement2:
        assert(True)
    else:
        assert(False)
    # Verifies if the date is between the 1st and the 26th then adds 2 days
    if dateelement1 <= 26 and dateelement1 >= 1:
        dateelement3 = dateelement2 + 2

    # if date is greater than 26th, it subtracts 2 days
    else:
        dateelement3 = dateelement2 - 2

    # System selects the date that is either 2 days after or 2 days before from previous if statement
    if self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ui-datepicker-div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(4) > a').text == str(dateelement3):
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ui-datepicker-div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(4) > a').click()
        time.sleep(15)
    # System displays a screenshot of the selected date
        print "System should display the day as " + str(dateelement3) + " for the current month in screenshot"
        self.driver.save_screenshot('datepicker_selected.png')
    else:
        assert(False)
```

Currently I'm just creating a screenshot to visually verify that the date is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get the value of the attached to the datepicker `input`, for example:

```
input_element = driver.find_element_by_id('datepicker')
print input_element.get_attribute('value')
```